# Which of the followings is more efficient?

Tags: php

Assume I have the following settings array:

```
$settings = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
```

Which of the following set of codes is more efficient, in terms of speed & memory usage ?

**Set 1**

```
foreach($settings as $k => $v) {
    define($k, $v);
}
```

**Set 2**

```
while (list($key, $value) = each($settings)) {
    define($key, $value);
}
```

They have the same results.

---

**UPDATE**: Added benchmark results

Here are the benchmark codes:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$arr = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) {
  $arr['rec_' . $i] = md5(time());
}

$start = microtime(true);

foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    define($k, $v);
}

$end = microtime(true);
echo 'Method 1 - Foreach: ' . round($end - $start, 2) . PHP_EOL;

$arr = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) {
  $arr['rec2_' . $i] = md5(time());
}


$start = microtime(true);

while (list($key, $value) = each($arr)) {
  define($key, $value);
}

$end = microtime(true);
echo 'Method 2 - While List Each: ' . round($end - $start, 2) . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

After quite a few benchmark runs, I found that `foreach()` is around 2x to 3x faster than `while-list-each` approach.

Hope the above benchmark is useful to future audience.

Comment: possible duplicate at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847502/for-loop-vs-while-loop-vs-foreach-loop-php

Comment: might be a duplicate, but mixing with `list()` and `each()` make the comparison case more complicated.

Comment: Why don't you benchmark it for your self

Comment: @Dagon added back benchmark results after half year...

Comment: Your benchmark is pretty self-explanatory. The question is: do you have 100K items in the settings list in your application? And, if you create constants out of them using this approach, do you really use all of them in the rest of the code?

Comment: Agreed with you. 100,000 records are for benchmark only. Normally I will use around 10 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one hand, `foreach` need to worry about [traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php), so in this case may be little overhead compering with `each` in `while`.

But on other hand, using `each` and `while` you are using two two language constructs and one function.

`Also` you do need to remember that after `each` will finished, the cursor  will be in the last element of array, if it iterate threw all elements.